# Can't prove that Fast Magnetosonic Wave's proper speed is given by the following formula

Tags: waves, plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

So, suppose a magnetosonic disturbance, it is proven that (You can also see it in [Richard Fitzpatrick's *Plasma Physics* online text](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/Plasmahtml/node65.html)), that the Fast Magnetosonic Wave is equal to
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\omega}{k}=\bigg\{ \dfrac{1}{2}\big[ V_a^2+c_s^2\pm \sqrt{(V_a^2+c_s^2)^2-4V_a^2c_s^2\cos^2\theta} \big] \bigg\}^{1/2}
\end{equation}

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{k} $ and $ \vec{B}$. Let it be 90 and this gives 
$$
\dfrac{\omega}{k}=\sqrt{(V_a^2+c_s^2)} $$

Now we define $\sigma = \dfrac{V_a^2}{c^2} = \dfrac{B_o^2}{4\pi\rho c^2}$
and this gives
$$
\dfrac{\omega}{k}=c \sqrt{(\sigma+\beta_s^2)} $$

And that's the result I get.

Now on Wikipedia, [the fast magnetosonic speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosonic_wave) is given as 
$$
\dfrac{\omega}{k}=c \dfrac{\sqrt{(V_a^2+c_s^2)}}{\sqrt{V_a^2 + c^2}} $$ which is not the same, and on a lot of papers I see the result:
$$
\dfrac{\omega}{k}=c \sqrt{\dfrac{(\sigma(1+\beta_s^2)+\beta_s^2}{(1+\beta_s^2)(1+\sigma)}} $$

where they also suppose $\theta = 90$  and is actually the desirable result.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
$$V_a= \dfrac{B_o}{\sqrt{4\pi\rho}} = \text{Alfven Speed}$$
$$\beta_s= c_s/c = \text{Sound Velocity/c}$$

Comment: As written, this looks like a homework-like question, which is generally considered off-topic. It could be made on-topic if you asked about qualitative differences or underlying assumptions between the equations.

Comment: It's not homework. I could post my velocity as it is, but I just want to find out how the other equations came out.

Comment: I mostly agree with your assessment (that it's not a homework question), but the way it's phrased is typical of homework-like questions posted here; hence, my suggestion to rephrase it. I suspect that asking for difference might lead to seeing how the different forms arise, but I'm not familiar with the latter two formulations, only the first.

Comment: Your magnetosonic speed (i.e., 2nd to last equation) is missing a square term under the square root term in the numerator.  This is a limit of the fast mode where $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2$.  As for your last expression, you need to define the terms (actually, you should do this for all expressions).

Comment: could you be more accurate? ( I don't get it) (Edited)

Answer (score 2):

## **Definitions**

- $\varepsilon_{o}$ is the [permittivity of free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity)
- $\mu_{o}$ is the [permeability of free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism))
- $Z_{s}$ is the charge state of species $s$ (e.g., +1 for protons)
- $e$ is the [elementary charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge)
- $\mathbf{B}_{o}$ is the quasi-static magnetic field
- $m_{s}$ is the mass of species $s$
- $n_{s}$ is the number density of species $s$
- $P_{s}$ is the scalar pressure of species $s$
- $\mathbf{U}_{s}$ is the bulk flow velocity of of species $s$ (e.g., see velocity moment definitions at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218643/59023)
- $\Omega_{cs} = \tfrac{ Z_{s} \ e \ B_{o} }{ \Gamma \ m_{s} }$ is the [gyrofrequency (or cyclotron frequency)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_cyclotron_resonance) of species $s$ and $\Gamma$ is the relativistic [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor)
- $\omega_{ps} = \sqrt{\tfrac{ n_{s} \ Z_{s}^{2} \ e^{2} }{ \varepsilon_{o} \ m_{s} }}$ is the [plasma frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation) of species $s$
- $C_{s}^{2} = \tfrac{ \gamma \ P }{ \rho }$ is the [speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) squared where $P$ is the scalar pressure, $\gamma$ is the [ratio of specific heats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio), and $\rho$ is the mass density here
- $V_{A}^{2} = \tfrac{ B_{o}^{2} }{ \sqrt{ \mu_{o} \ \rho } }$ is the [Alfven speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfv%C3%A9n_wave) squared

## **Dispersion Relation**

In general, to find the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) or other properties of a wave mode, one starts by deriving a [dispersion relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation), $D(\mathbf{k}, \omega)$.  The dispersion relation is derived from the equation:
$$
\mathbf{n} \times \left( \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{E} \right) + \overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{K}} \cdot \mathbf{E} = 0 \tag{1}
$$
where $\mathbf{n}$ is the [index of refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) and $\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{K}}$ is the dielectric tensor (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138460/59023 for further discussion of derivation of Equation 1).  We rewrite Equation 1 in the tensor form $\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{D}} \cdot \mathbf{E} = 0$.  If $\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{D}}$ has a determinant that goes to zero, then there is a non-trivial solution for $\mathbf{E}$.

The solutions to the dispersion relation give the wave frequency, $\omega$, as a function of the wavevector, $\mathbf{k}$.

## **MHD Fast Mode**

The simplest form of the fast mode dispersion relation for arbitrary propagation angle, $\theta$, with respect to $\mathbf{B}_{o}$ starts by *linearizing* [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction), the mass [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation), the [momentum equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)), and an equation of state (e.g., our expression for the speed of sound in the **Definitions** section above).  By linearize, I mean that we assume any relevant quantity can be rewritten as $Q = Q_{o} + \delta Q$ where the $Q_{o}$ is the quasi-static term (i.e., roughly constant or background term) and $\delta Q$ is the fluctuating term.  We also assume that $\delta Q \propto e^{i \left( \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega \ t \right)}$ (actually this comes from a [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) but I it does not change much in way of the process).

The latter assumption leads to the following $\partial / \partial t \rightarrow -i \ \omega$ and $\nabla \rightarrow i \ \mathbf{k}$ and that either of these operators acting on any $Q_{o}$ term goes to zero.

To start, the four equations I mentioned are given, to first order, as:
$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{ \partial \ \delta \rho }{ \partial t } + \nabla \cdot \left( \mathbf{U}_{o} \ \delta \rho + \delta \mathbf{U} \ \rho_{o} \right) & = 0 \tag{2a} \\
  \rho_{o} \frac{ \partial \ \delta \mathbf{U} }{ \partial t } & = \delta \mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B}_{o} + \mathbf{j}_{o} \times \delta \mathbf{B} - \nabla \left( \delta P \right) \tag{2b} \\
  \frac{ \partial \ \delta \mathbf{B} }{ \partial t } & = \nabla \times \left( \delta \mathbf{U} \times \mathbf{B}_{o} + \mathbf{U}_{o} \times \delta \mathbf{B} \right) \tag{2c} \\
  \delta P & = \gamma \left( \frac{ P_{o} }{ \rho_{o} } \right) \delta \rho \tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
We can greatly simplify this in a few ways.  The first is that we just move into the bulk flow rest frame, i.e., $\mathbf{U}_{o} \rightarrow 0$.  The second is to recognize that there are no $\mathbf{j}_{o}$ terms, since those would imply that $\nabla \times \mathbf{B}_{o} \neq 0$ which would violate our assumptions.  Then we have:
$$
\begin{align}
  -i \ \omega \ \delta \rho + i \ \rho_{o} \ \mathbf{k} \cdot \delta \mathbf{U} & = 0 \tag{3a} \\
  -i \ \omega \ \rho_{o} \ \delta \mathbf{U} & = \frac{ i }{ \mu_{o} } \left( \mathbf{k} \times \delta \mathbf{B} \right) \times \mathbf{B}_{o} - i \ \mathbf{k} \ \delta P \tag{3b} \\
  -i \ \omega \ \delta \mathbf{B} & = i \ \mathbf{k} \times \left( \delta \mathbf{U} \times \mathbf{B}_{o} \right) \tag{3c} \\
  \delta P & = C_{s}^{2} \ \delta \rho \tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$

We can solve for $\delta \rho$ in Equation 3a to find a new relationship for $\delta P$ from Equation 3d to then insert into Equation 3b.  This new form of Equation 3b combined with 3c gives (after some symbol gymnastics):
$$
\omega^{2} \ \delta \mathbf{U} = \frac{ 1 }{ \mu_{o} \ \rho_{o} } \left\{ \mathbf{k} \times \left[ \mathbf{k} \times \left( \delta \mathbf{U} \times \mathbf{B}_{o} \right) \right] \right\} \times \mathbf{B}_{o} + C_{s}^{2} \ \mathbf{k} \left( \mathbf{k} \cdot \delta \mathbf{U} \right) \tag{4}
$$

To further simplify, we define the coordinate basis such that the following are satisfied:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{B}_{o} & = B_{o} \ \hat{\mathbf{z}} \tag{5a} \\
  \mathbf{k} & = \left( k \ \sin{\theta}, 0, k \ \cos{\theta} \right) \tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
and then define $V_{ph} = \omega/k$ as the phase speed and rewrite Equation 4 in matrix form and after (significant) simplification we have:
$$
\begin{align}
  0 & = \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c c }
    V_{ph}^{2} - C_{s}^{2} \ \sin^{2}{\theta} - V_{A}^{2} & 0 & - C_{s}^{2} \ \sin{\theta} \ \cos{\theta} \\
    0 & V_{ph}^{2} - V_{A}^{2} \ \cos^{2}{\theta} & 0 \\
    - C_{s}^{2} \ \sin{\theta} \ \cos{\theta} & 0 & V_{ph}^{2} - C_{s}^{2} \ \cos^{2}{\theta}
  \end{array} \right] \cdot \left[
  \begin{array}{ c }
    \delta U_{x} \\
    \delta U_{y} \\
    \delta U_{z} \\
  \end{array} \right]
  \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

The determinant of the first matrix gives the dispersion relation:
$$
D\left( \mathbf{k}, \omega \right) = \left( V_{ph}^{2} - V_{A}^{2} \ \cos^{2}{\theta} \right) \left[ V_{ph}^{4} - V_{ph}^{2} \left( V_{A}^{2} + C_{s}^{2} \right) + V_{A}^{2} \ C_{s}^{2} \ \cos^{2}{\theta} \right] = 0 \tag{7}
$$

It is then easy to show that there are three roots, one of which is the fast mode root given by:
$$
\begin{align}
2 \ V_{f}^{2} & = \left( V_{A}^{2} + C_{s}^{2} \right) + \sqrt{ \left( V_{A}^{2} + C_{s}^{2} \right)^{2} - 4 \ V_{A}^{2} \ C_{s}^{2} \ \cos^{2}{\theta} } \tag{8a} \\
& = \left( V_{A}^{2} + C_{s}^{2} \right) + \sqrt{ \left( V_{A}^{2} - C_{s}^{2} \right)^{2} + 4 \ V_{A}^{2} \ C_{s}^{2} \ \sin^{2}{\theta} } \tag{8b}
\end{align}
$$
where I have used $V_{f} = V_{ph}$ for the fast mode.

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing, just not catching that these are not truly equivalent expressions.  For instance, the form shown after your link to the Wikipedia article is missing a square in the numerator (i.e., the parentheses should be squared), which just reduces it to the second expression you show.

Let's start with the form:
$$
V_{f} = c \ \sqrt{ \frac{ \sigma \left( 1 + \beta_{s}^{2} \right) + \beta_{s}^{2} }{ \left( 1 + \beta_{s}^{2} \right) \left( 1 + \sigma \right) } } \tag{9}
$$
Now let us take the limit where $\beta_{s}^{2} \ll 1$ and $\sigma \ll 1$, then Equation 9 goes to:
$$
\begin{align}
  \lim_{\beta_{s}^{2} \ll 1 \\ \sigma \ll 1} \left[ \left( 1 + \beta_{s}^{2} \right) \left( 1 + \sigma \right) \right]^{-1/2} & \approx 1 - \frac{ \beta_{s}^{2} }{ 2 } - \frac{ \sigma }{ 2 } \tag{10a} \\
  V_{f} & \simeq c \ \sqrt{ \left[ \sigma \left( 1 + \beta_{s}^{2} \right) + \beta_{s}^{2} \right] \left( 1 - \frac{ \beta_{s}^{2} }{ 2 } - \frac{ \sigma }{ 2 } \right) } \tag{10b} \\
  & = c \ \sqrt{ \sigma + \beta_{s}^{2} - \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } \left( \sigma^{2} + \beta_{s}^{4} + \beta_{s}^{2} \ \sigma^{2} + \beta_{s}^{4} \ \sigma \right) } \tag{10c} \\
  & \approx c \ \sqrt{ \sigma + \beta_{s}^{2} } \tag{10d} \\
  V_{f} & \approx \sqrt{ V_{A}^{2} + C_{s}^{2} } \tag{10e}
\end{align}
$$
where Equation 10e is the form shown in your second and fourth expressions (and the result found in the limit as $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2$ for Equations 8a and 8b) and Equation 10d is your third expression.

## **Justify Assumptions**

I wrote a detailed answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023 that provides several estimates for typical values of $V_{A}$ and $C_{s}$ in the interplanetary medium.

Under most conditions both $C_{s}$ and $V_{A}$ satisfy < 100 km/s.  The typical values one often quotes for reference are in the ~20-50 km/s range.  The only place where $V_{A}$ approaches the speed of light, of which I am aware, is in the auroral acceleration region near Earth.  Similarly, $C_{s}$ is almost never near $c$, except perhaps within stars.

**Side Note:**  As an aside, I have been working in space plasma physics for over a decade and have never seen the form for the fast mode speed given by Equation 9.  This is not to say that it is not used or irrelevant, just interesting because I have read a substantial fraction of the literature on these modes.

Comment: I don't think OPs issue was on deriving the fast magnetosonic wave but why there are three different formulations that are each described as fast magnetosonic waves (but don't appear to be derivable from one-another)\

Comment: Really Thank for all the analysis!! Yes that's the result I get also, following almost the exact same way. BUT, for example on this paper this is the result( https://image.prntscr.com/image/BTccOnmsQRG-YsVnDwD7eQ.png ) and Wiki's formula is different too. But with your way ( and the same i did) can't reach those equations

Comment: @KyleKanos - Yes, it appears I did miss that part when I first read their question.  I have updated my answer to address their issue.

Comment: Really thanks for the equations there, they actually helped me. There is actaully one problem. Equation 9 - The same I posted on screenshot-, as it says on text, it's for the $\theta = 90$ case. So, from Equation 8a , and for $cos(\pi /2) = 0,$  we get the result 10e! BUT, we made no assumptions for $\sigma << 1, \beta_s << 1.$  So how can I basically prove equation 9, which seems kinda more general, although it covers only the case $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{B} = 0 $ , or $\theta = 90$

Comment: @BillyMatlock - The two speeds, $V_{A}$ and $C_{s}$, are very rarely near the speed of light.  The only place I know where $V_{A}$ approaches $c$ is in the auroral acceleration region near Earth.  Everywhere else of which I am aware the following is satisfied $V_{A} \ll c$.  The speed of sound is rarely very high except within stars etc.  I will add a few more details to justify my answer.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I see.  I make a dissertation project on Cosmic Jets which are heavily magnetized, and the Va is almost c, and I'm Obligated to use RMHD models on the Rarefaction Waves, so I guess I had to prove that equation 9, don't I?


Also the paper from which i got equation 9 is " Rarefaction wave in relativistic steady magnetohydrodynamic flows"

Comment: @BillyMatlock - Ah okay, that helps.  Generally such expressions are not pulled from the ether.  Meaning, follow the literature trail and you will find the following paper that does derive this form:  [http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013MNRAS.434.1779S](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013MNRAS.434.1779S).  Actually, most of the time when you find a form that is not clear/obvious, if you run through the references you will find the original derivation at some point (usually).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63452/discussion-between-billy-matlock-and-honeste-vivere).